# How to politely, mildly, and tactfully ask for a minor revision before the presentation of the conference paper?

Tags: publications, graduate-school, conference, etiquette

I just have a paper accepted at a very selective conference but now I am going to make a minor revision before my presentation because I found a few grammar errors. The organizer seems unaware of my errors.

What is a mild and roundabout way to inform the organizer that I would like to "update" the paper? I do not want them to think that I was ignorant or negligent.

Does saying something like "I would like to do a minor revision" sounds too formal and could potentially scare the organizers, making them double-think about the acceptance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm no journal editor, but the following seems like it would do the trick:

> Are you accepting any revisions on accepted manuscripts? I've noticed a few stylistic things that I'd like to fix (nothing that impacts the results or the page count).